# How to get default value of python ldap option

Tags: python, ldap

```
import ldap,ldif

l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://RIO-PC:636')
l.simple_bind_s('cn=Manager,dc=micmiu,dc=com','secret')
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 10.0)
```

I could call get_option to get the option value, but how could I get back the original timeout value before setting it as 10.0?

Answer (score 0):

Why not cache him before set the new value?

```
original_timeout = l.get_option(ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT)
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 10.0)
```

Wish i could help (and understand your original problem).

Comment: Thanks, your solution work, but I would like to know the solution without caching the value